# Sorted parameters in query string from two JavaScript object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, query-string

What's the best way to receive a sorted parameter query string from two JavaScript objects using `querystring`, `qs`, etc?

I am adding properties from obj2 to obj1:

```
for (var attrname in obj2) { obj1[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
```

`obj1` ends up with a bunch of properties.

After I `stringify` `obj1`, I need all parameters in the query string to be alphabetically sorted by key:

```
a=v1&b=v2&c=v3
```

Comment: JS objects are unordered.

Comment: Why would you need the query string parameters in any specific order?

Comment: @Scimonster I know.  That's why the question.

Comment: @Guffa That's a requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As object properties can not be sorted (their order is unspecified), you would need to put them in an array.

You can make an object that handles a key-value pair:

```
function KeyValue(key, value) {
  this.key = key;
  this.value = value;
}

KeyValue.prototype = {
  toString: function() {
    return encodeURIComponent(this.key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(this.value);
  }
};
```

By creating an array of `KeyValue` objects from the properties in the object, you can then sort them on the key, and just use `join` to make the query string:

```
var obj1 = { x: '1 2 3', b: 42, f: 'x<y' };

var query = [];
for (var key in obj1) {
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        query.push(new KeyValue(key, obj1[key]));
    }
}

query.sort(function(a, b){ return a.key < b.key ? -1 : 1 });

var queryString = query.join('&');
```

The variable `queryString` now contains `b=42&f=x%3Cy&x=1%202%203`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/915wt4j4/

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you. I had to add `var` before `key` in `for (key in obj1) {` line in order for the code to work in a function

Comment: @kyrylkov: Ah, naturally. :)